# Why my program output is showing invalid Int input even though there is no syntax error?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am fairly new in Tkinter GUI and I there are still quite a lot I don't understand.
I am really stuck with my program and I really need someone's guidance to show me why I am having issues with my program.

The problem I have it that I want to deposit a certain amount of money to the bank and calculate it with the current available balance, but when I enter the amount, the output I get is 'Invalid amount entered', even though I am entering the right number, such as 20 or 50 and so on.

Can someone please help me:

Here is the code:

```
class Demo4():
    def __init__(self,master):
            self.master=master
            self.frame=Frame(self.master)
            self.frame.grid()
            self.master.minsize(width=400,height=120)
            self.master.title('Deposit')
            self.label_1=Label(self.frame,text='Deposit Amount:')
            self.label_1.grid(row=1,padx=7,pady=5,sticky='we')
            self.label_2=Label(self.frame,text='Balance:')
            self.label_2.grid(row=2,padx=7,pady=5,sticky='e')
            self.button_1=Button(self.frame,text='Calculate',width=8,height=3,
                                 command=self.MakeDeposit)
            self.button_1.grid(row=1,column=10,sticky='e'+'w',padx=7,rowspan=2)
            self.entry_1=Entry(self.frame,width=40)
            self.entry_1.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky='e'+'w',columnspan=3)
            self.entry_2=Entry(self.frame,width=40)
            self.entry_2.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='e'+'w',columnspan=3)
            self.logLabel=Label(self.frame,text='DEPOSIT',font="Helvetica 10 bold italic")
            self.logLabel.grid(row=0,padx=5,pady=5)

            self.e2=IntVar()
            self.e1=IntVar()
```

I know that the first part of the code Class Demo4 is working because I tried to test it on its own. I think that the problem is the second part of `MakeDeposit` function.

```
def MakeDeposit(self):
    self.e2=IntVar()
    self.e1=IntVar()
    num2 = self.e2.get()
    balance = int(num2)
    num1 = self.e1.get()
    depositAmount = int(num1)
    while depositAmount<=0:
       self.errorLabel = Label(self.frame,text="That was not a valid amount").grid(row=3,columnspan=5)
       return
       if self.depositAmount>0:
           self.textLabel = Label(self.frame,text=("Your new balance is:\n")).grid(row=3,columnspan=5)
           self.newBalanceLabel = Label(self.frame,text=(balance+depositAmount)).grid(row=4,columnspan=5, pady=7)
```

Now, the problem I am encountering is that when I enter the first amount of the deposit and add the balance available to the deposit(as that is the only way I know how to code it) I get a dialog box, which says that the 'entered amount is invalid', which means that the while loop is not functioning properly. Unfortunately, I tried different variations and  it still does not work.

Please help, I am really stuck.

---

I also tried to change the layout of the variables and names, but its still giving me the same error:

Here is the changes:

```
class Demo4():

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.frame=Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.master.minsize(width=400,height=120)

        self.e_2=IntVar()
        self.e_1=IntVar()

        self.master.title('Deposit')
        self.label_1=Label(self.frame,text='Deposit Amount:')
        self.label_1.grid(row=1,padx=7,pady=5,sticky='we')
        self.label_2=Label(self.frame,text='Balance:')
        self.label_2.grid(row=2,padx=7,pady=5,sticky='e')
        self.button_1=Button(self.frame,text='Calculate',width=8,height=3,command=self.MakeDeposit)
        self.button_1.grid(row=1,column=10,sticky='e'+'w',padx=7,rowspan=2)
        self.entry_1=Entry(self.frame,width=40,textvariable=self.e_1)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky='e'+'w',columnspan=3)
        self.entry_2=Entry(self.frame,width=40,textvariable=self.e_2)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='e'+'w',columnspan=3)
        self.logLabel=Label(self.frame,text='DEPOSIT',font="Helvetica 10 bold italic")
        self.logLabel.grid(row=0,padx=5,pady=5)

    def MakeDeposit(self):
        self.entry_2=IntVar()
        self.entry_1=IntVar()

        num2 = self.entry_2.get()
        balance = int(num2)
        num1 = self.entry_1.get()
        depositAmount = int(num1)
        while depositAmount<=0:
            self.errorLabel = Label(self.frame,text="That was not a valid amount").grid(row=3,columnspan=5)
            return
        if depositAmount>0:
            self.textLabel = Label(self.frame,text=("Your new balance is:\n")).grid(row=3,columnspan=5)
            self.newBalanceLabel = Label(self.frame,text=(balance+depositAmount)).grid(row=4,columnspan=5, pady=7)
```

Comment: One major problem is when you assign the result of calling the `grid` method immediately after creating a widget because it returns `None`, **not** the widget as your code assumes.